# Reconstructing a metric from local data

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, riemannian-geometry

Suppose you have a Riemannian manifold $\mathcal{M}$ where the metric $g$ is unknown. Let $U$ be an open subset of the manifold with a coordinate chart $x^\mu$. Now imagine that for each fixed coordinate value $x_0^\mu$ you can compute the curvature tensor $R(0)$ in Riemann normal coordinates adapted to the anchor point $x_0$. With only this data, is it possible to reconstruct the metric on $U$ in the original coordinates $x^\mu$, or on any open subset of $U$? If not, is there any simple additional data which can be specified to make the problem well posed?

Comment: Offhand, it seems to me you would need information on the interaction of these different normal neighborhoods. How do you know what “neighboring points” are without knowing the metric?

Comment: That's a good point. I suppose I had in mind (which I will edit the question to reflect) that one also had a coordinate label for each of the points $p$ in such a way that one can talk about ``closeness'' in the sense of taking the coincident limit of said coordinates.

Comment: I don't think we can answer your question until you're able to write it more precisely and rigorously.